# Similar Matrices have the same rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Prove that :- If $2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar then they will have the same rank.

Proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337598/prove-the-similar-matrices-have-the-same-rank) but I can't understand both answers which are related to  image and kernel. I have seen all the video lectures of Prof. Gilbert Strang but I have not seen these things in those lectures. I only know that $A$ and $B$ are similar iff $A$ = $MBM^{-1}$ for some invertible square matrix $M$ but I can't proceed further. Is there any simple proof of it ?
Please help.

Comment: What definition of rank are you working with? Usually, rank is defined as the dimension of the image, so it's hard to talk about rank without talking about images...

Comment: Isn't the rank also the number of non zero eigen values? And similar matrices have the same spectrum

Comment: @FareedAF The rank is only the number of non zero eigen values if the matrices are square.

Comment: @5xum The OP is clearly talking about square matrices, otherwise the product $MBM^{-1}$ doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favourite proof goes along the lines of

> $rk(B)\geq rk(MBM^{-1}) = rk(A)$, as multiplying can only reduce rank (or keep it unchanged), never increase it. Now note that $B = M^{-1}AM$, so we similarily get $rk(A)\geq rk(M^{-1}AM) = rk(B)$

Comment: Thank you!  @Arthur